# Parsley.js - Re-validate a field after selecting an auto-complete value or drag-and-drop

Tags: autocomplete, drag-and-drop, parsley.js

After parsley validation, an error message may be displayed near a field.

If the user **types** a corrected value, the field is automatically re-validated, the message will disappear, and the field will be marked with success.

However, if a valid value is then entered by either i) selecting from the field's "auto-complete" dropdown  **OR** ii) by dragging-and-dropping into the field, this will not invoke the re-validation, and the error message remains even though the field now has a valid value.

Example...

[image]

Q: How to force fields to re-validate upon selecting value from the browser's auto-complete dropdown/drag-and-drop?

(I realise you can specify no auto-complete on fields, but this may not always be desirable, and doesn't solve the drag-and-drop issue.)

Answer (score 1):

In autofill function add this code to validate the autofill fields again:

```
function autofill_function_name(){
   your code;
   $("#autofill_field_name").parsley().validate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use bootstrapValidator for validation.

Then, you have to revalidate the field after fetching data

```
$('yourForm).bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'inputName');
```